# C# - unexpected result in populating ComboBox with MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, combobox

I my class `DBConnect`, I have this function to populate a ComboBox to database based on input query:

```
public void POPULATE_COMBOBOX(string query, ComboBox myComboBox)
{
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(myDataTable);
        myComboBox.DataSource = myDataTable; 

        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

And here's how I use it

> DBConnect.POPULATE_COMBOBOX("SELECT NAME FROM users", comboBox_Name);

I have 3 rows in column `NAME`, and I expect those 3 names will be displayed in my `comboBox_Name`. However instead, I got 3 lines of `System.Data.DataRowView` in my combobox. Any idea how to convert those DataRowView to string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell combobox what column to display.

```
//Preparation
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("Name1");
dt.Rows.Add("Name2");

//Setup data binding
myComboBox.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
myComboBox.ValueMember = "Name";
```

Then `SelectedItem` gets the actual ComboBox item (in this case a DataRowView), whereas `SelectedValue` gets the value of the property you specified as the ValueMember of the ComboBox

Or another way how to populate your `ComboBox` is:

```
MySqlDataReader sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    myComboBox.Items.Add(sqlReader["Name"].ToString());
}

sqlReader.Close();
```

Comment: I got an error "Cannot bind to the new display member." on the third line

Comment: also, an explanation of what that does would be so helpful :)

Comment: I accept the second answer as the easiest working method, thanks!